# Finding Laurent of $ \frac{e^{1/z}}{1-z} $

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

The question is: Determine the Laurent expansion in the region $0<|z|<1$?
$$ \frac{e^{1/z}}{1-z} $$
Here is how i have tried to solve it but my answer is not correct and i don't know why?
$$e^{1/z}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^kk!}=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^22!}+\frac{1}{z^33!}+... $$
$$\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n=1+z+z^2+...$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^22!}+\frac{1}{z^33!}+...\right)\left(1+z+z^2+...\right)  $$
Any suggestion would be great, thanks

Comment: Are you really after the Laurent expansion? Or are you after the residue at $0$?

Comment: Your $e^{1/z}$ series should start with $1+1/z$, i.e. sum over $n\ge\color{blue}{0}$.

Comment: @J.G. but is it not the case that the principle part should start with index number 1?

Comment: @simon $e^{1/z}/(1-z)=(\color{blue}{1+}1/z+\cdots)(1+z+z^2+\cdots)$ can't just lose the blue part.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The Laurent series centered on zero has the form

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n z^n.$$

Hence you need to use Cauchy product to write

$$\left(1 +\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^22!}+\frac{1}{z^33!}+...\right)\left(1+z+z^2+...\right)  $$

with the appropriate form.

Alternatively, use the fact that

$$a_n =\frac{1}{2i \pi} \oint_\gamma \frac{f(z) dz}{z^{n+1}}$$ where $\gamma$ is the counterclockwise circle centered on $0$ with radius $1/2$.